# Unable to find web elements, using selenium::remote::driver perl bindings, whenever base URI changes from default website url

Tags: html, perl, dom, selenium-webdriver

I am writing test scripts for a website using selenium webdriver's perl bindings. The problem I am facing is mentioned below:

I am not able to find some of the web elements (tried every approach: xpath, id, css, etc.) which exist on the web page, although I can click on them as a user.
After debugging through firebug I found that there is a property called base URI. And this has a different value from one web element to another. So whenever BASE URI = URL, I am able find elements and work on them.

But if BASE URI IS NOT EQUAL TO URL I am unable to find web elements.

Here is a sample code for successfull case:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::More "no_plan";
use Test::Exception;
use TAP::Harness;
use Data::Dumper;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Remote::WDKeys;
my $url = 'https://www.xyz.com/';
my $sel = new Selenium::Remote::Driver('browser_name' => 'firefox',
                                              'platform' => 'VISTA');
        ok(defined $sel, 'Object loaded fine...');
        ok($sel->isa('Selenium::Remote::Driver'), '...and of right type');
         $sel->get("$url");
    is ($sel->get_title(), 'xyz','Got the right title');
        my $elem = $sel->find_element('html/body/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/div/center/div/ul/li[1]/a');
        ok(defined $elem, 'packageLink web element defined');
        $elem->click();
```

In this case the DOM structure shows that base uri is the same as url.

Now for unsuccessful the case, the DOM shows the base URI as https://www.xyz.com/epg.php

In the above mentioned code, if I use the $sel->navigate(https://www.xyz.com/epg.php) command just before the find element command then the script will be able to find the elements.  But it will be just a static page click and will give no response.

I am a first time user of HTML related tasks. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks,
Abhishek